# A Cheap Way for Seeing 1000nm to 1600nm Light

Tags: infrared-radiation, camera

I have started a project in infrared where the spectrum covers 1000nm to 1600nm. A silicon based image sensors can see up to about 1000nm, while an iPhone attached FLIR camera can see from 8 – 14 µm, according to the spectral response in the spec sheet. I suppose an InGaAs image sensor can be used for 1000-1600nm but it is quite expensive. Are there cheaper options?

Comment: Here's a list of the common ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrow-gap_semiconductor . Anything not listed there will likely be even more expensive.